# Importing data into existing columns in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I am trying to figure out how I could import data from plain text into an excel table that is already created.

For example, I have a table in Excel similar to that below:

```
Class     Name     Status     Comment
Mr. Bob   George   
Ms. Sam   Phil
Mr. Bob   Carrie
```

I have created a python script that parses some folders and creates a text file like below:

```
Class     Name     Status     Comment
          George   F          Try Studying Harder!
          Phil     B-         Nice Report!
          Carrie   A          Excellent!
```

Is there a way to import the text file into Excel so that it matches the student names and imports the status and comment into the correct columns?

Comment: Is editing your python script an option?  If instead of spaces you would add a comma to create a csv file for simple import into excel?

Comment: Editing the script is an option. The file is delimited by tabs which I have not properly displayed here. The problem I am running into, however, is that there doesn't seem to be an option to match up the data rows to import data.

Comment: As @KarlKristjansson said, use comma's instead of tabs.

Comment: No, there is no option of importing select columns and sort into a preexisting table. Try in ribbon: " Data--> Text import" and try the "tab delimiter" option as well as "fixed" and see if that will import your file properly to a new sheet in excel.  If this works for you, then no need to edit your python script.  All you'll need is a vba script to cycle through your imported table and fill in your excel database, then delete your new sheet.